# (UE4) How to properly render after transforming the bones of UPoseableMeshComponent

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

- I am trying to transform bones within UE4 (4.25) using UPoseableMeshComponent. ([image of initial state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZUCg.jpg))
- However, after I transform the bones using SetBoneTransformByName, the rendering gets into some weird state, below is not motion blur, is just a pose after applied SetBoneTransformByName ([image after transform blurred rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvN2A.jpg)). Although `Unlit` rendering seems just fine.
- After I call AActor::SetActorHiddenInGame(true) to set invisible, and then AActor::SetActorHiddenInGame(false) to show the actor again, the rendering will be fixed. ([Image after hide/show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8Fer.jpg))
- The code is purely in c++ (no BP), I first create custom Character with SkeletalMesh and added UPoseableMeshComponent in code something like in below:

```
void AMyCharacter::CreatePoseableMesh() {
    USkeletalMeshComponent* skeletalMesh = GetMesh();
    UPoseableMeshComponent* poseMesh =
        NewObject<UPoseableMeshComponent>(this, UPoseableMeshComponent::StaticClass());
    if (poseMesh) {
        poseMesh->RegisterComponent();
        poseMesh->SetWorldLocation(location);
        poseMesh->SetWorldRotation(rotation);
        poseMesh->AttachToComponent(GetRootComponent(),FAttachmentTransformRules::KeepRelativeTransform);
        poseMesh->SetSkeletalMesh(skeletalMesh->SkeletalMesh);
        poseMesh->SetVisibility(true);
        skeletalMesh->SetVisibility(false);
    }
}
```

Are there something missing to set in UPoseableMeshComponent?

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, but I think this is because setting bone transform manually doesn't write to the velocity buffer, and temporal AA doesn't know that something moved, causing ugly blur.

If you switch to FXAA and the problem disappears - here's your hint.

There is a material node called Previous Frame Switch - you can control the velocity buffer through it using a custom parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Self solved(sort of..). I tried with BP first, where even BP needs to SetVisibility(false) then SetVisibility(true) on PoseableMeshComponent to render properly. Maybe a minor bug within UE4.

```
TMap<FString, FTransform> const& transforms; // given. map of bone name and its transform.
poseMesh->SetVisibility(false); // PoseableMeshComponent. Hide once
for (auto& x : transforms) {
    poseMesh->SetBoneTransformByName(FName(*x.Key), x.Value, EBoneSpaces::WorldSpace);
}
poseableMesh->SetVisibility(true); // show it.
```

seems to be the workaround for now.